# Getting the best category for a topic in Freebase

Tags: freebase

How to get the best (top) category for a topic ?

For example the movie "Life Is Beautiful" has a notable type "Award-Winning Work". I can not use this category. I'd like to know that, over all categories, the best choice is "/film/film" and not "/award/award_winning_work".

Is it possible to get the top category for a item ?

Thanks for your ideas,
Mickael.

@TomMorris: Yes, "category" in my context, means "type".

But for a particular topic, there could be many many types and I don't know which to choose without actually making some choices, for example decide that if "/film/film" is present, then it is the best category for my topic.

I would have imagined that Freebase would provide this "main type" out of the box. If you read the description of notable_type you can read "The way a topic's notable types is calculated is rather complex." If Freebase provide this service that requires complex calculation, then why not provide another service that would be something like a "main type" that would be the top type, that is, the top of the ontonlogy classification (a caniche is a dog which is a animal, etc... and somewhat stop at a significant level like "animal" that I would consider as my "main type"). Simply put, "Award Work" is not a good description of the topic "Life is beautiful". "Film" is a better description of it.

I am afraid you're right. I need to make my own choices betwwen all the "types" of the topics.

Comment: Is `category` the same thing as a Freebase Type in this context?  What are the definitions of `best` and `top`?  If you don't like Google's definition of notable, you'll need to provide your own definition (and be prepared to compute the result).

Comment: Thanks Tom. I replied in the description to be more specific (and my reply didn't fit the size limit of a comment anyway)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you refer to the the dumps or to one of the Api's.

Regarding the API's please check the search API (link below). There results includes score and notable type which attempts to indicate what is the most relevant entity with the name you are looking for. You can also include additional properties in the results but this is the basic result.

Regarding working directly from the dumps - I haven't found a solution for that except of implementing some mechanism myself.

https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?query=Life+is+beautiful&limit=10

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If you look at the following topic (or the json you just sent) you will see that there is only one notable type. And there is no scores for types (Film / Award-Winning Work / Award-Nominated Work / W Film / Netflix Title / Topic) So your solution does not work for me. I'm thinking I have to compute it myself. For example if I find Film, I just take it over other types. https://www.freebase.com/m/011yrp

Comment: For the problems I used Freebase - that's exactly the thing. For certain names the notable type "Award-Winning Work" is more improtant than "Film" and for others vice versa. Emphasizing this problem - how would you deal with a name that has two different entities - one is soccer player and the other is a politician? From my perspective ranking notable types is not the right way to go.